# Calling of another XML by View and Layout

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater

Every body I want to call another XML in my activity , i called my main xml as given below

```
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and my xml file is as follow-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/appbg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- listview -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/logo12"
        android:src="@drawable/logo12" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeLin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_icon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchLin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="15sp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cross1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@drawable/search"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linSortby"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvsortby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sortby"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPriceLH"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/priceLH"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPriceHL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text="@string/priceHL"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linPagingupper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linPaging"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPrev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@drawable/prev"
            android:src="@drawable/prev" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:text="@string/n1"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:text="@string/n2"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:text="@string/n3"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:text="@string/n4"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:text="@string/n5"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <!-- button -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@drawable/next"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/n1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listViewResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bluegrad"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/contact"
        android:src="@drawable/contact" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@drawable/home"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_other_xml"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

       </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>
```

and i want to call another activity by following code-

```
 LinearLayout lin_lay_add_paynow =                                                   
                                  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.add_other_xml);
    View pay_now_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pay_now_btn, null);
    lin_lay_add_paynow.addView(pay_now_view);
    TextView btn_pay_now = (TextView) pay_now_view.findViewById(R.id.btn_paynow);
    btn_pay_now.setText("mlsdmlsm");
```

and my pay_now_btn.xml is as follow

```
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn_paynow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

And problem is that i am doing every thing in correct manner . Then why my textview is not appearing . No error no exception then i am not able to see my textview of pay_now_btn.xml
Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: you have to set the content to the activity. you have set the main.xml Have a layout linear or relative layout in main.xml and add the view inflated to linearlayout or relative layout.

Comment: You have to add pay_now_view in any of layouts in main.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your response in 32 sec..I did not get what you want to say...main.xml is my parent layout. so i called it. Problem is not with main.xml

Comment: @selva   Thanks a lot.. will you post some more code ?\

Comment: @BlueGreen i posted it as an answer to make it clear.

Comment: @BlueGreen do you want to reuse the layout?

Comment: @BlueGreen do you need a home button you have the hardware home button. you have the hardware back button. so why do you need those?

Comment: @BlueGreen move your comments to discussion as this is leading to discussion, adding your inflated view as a footer to listview should work. What is the problem. pls be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the view into a layout in your `main.xml`

Create a layout in your `main.xml` 
In your code

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(pay_now_view);
```

Hope this works. Let me know if you face any problem

CODE :

Add this at bottom of main.xml before closing the last tag

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity after inflating and setText:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout); 
layout.addView(pay_now_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.

And you are inflating a view. But the inflated view is not added to the layout.

Have a another  `LinearLayout` in your `main.xml`. Place this linear layout to the required position or you can use `Relativelayout`.

Initialize it in `onCreate`

```
     LinearLayout ll = LinearLayout findViewById(R.id.ll);
```

Now add the inflated view to linearlayout

```
     ll.addView(pay_now_view);
```

Edit:

You can add the infalted view as a footer to listview as

```
     list.addFooterView(pay_now_view );
```

Comment: I tried this one but it is not working for me. I really feel fed-up from such a silly issue.

Comment: @BlueGreen i see no reason why it won't work. post your updated xml and code by editing the question

Comment: @BlueGreen you have this `LinearLayout lin_lay_add_paynow = ` should be  `LinearLayout lin_lay_add_paynow = LinearLayout findViewById(R.id.add_other_xml)`;

Comment: @BlueGreen use the id of the linear layout to initialize linearlayout.

Comment: @BlueGreen your initialization of LinearLayout is wrong it should be `LinearLayout lin_lay_add_paynow = LinearLayout findViewById(R.id.add_other_xml)`. pls update it. i have seen your code top to bottom.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34441/discussion-between-blue-green-and-raghunandan)

Comment: LinearLayout lin_lay_add_paynow = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_other_xml);

Comment: @BlueGreen instead of so many LinearLayouts have a RelativeLayout. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: ,,,, Thanks for your valueable time. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @BlueGreen i would remove all those home and back imagebuttons have edittest and listview add the view as a footer to listview.